# Spring findAll by parent propriety

Tags: spring, jhipster, findall

I'm using JHipster to generate an app. I have this map: Arquivo has OneToMany relationship with Tabela. And Tabela has OneToMany relationship with Campo.

Arquivo has a property called "versao" (string). I want to do something like:

```
Page<Campo> findAllByArquivoVersao(String versao, Pageable pageable);
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page br.com.app.repository.CampoRepository.findAllByArquivoVersao(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property arquivoVersao found for type Campo!

I'm able to do something like findAllByTabelaId...so my mapping is ok. How can I do a query filtering by a property of my parent's parent?

Comment: Try `findByArquivoVersao` (without `All` word)

Comment: I tried. Same error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data repository's method to find by the field of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193901/spring-data-repositorys-method-to-find-by-the-field-of-a-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories) on item 4.4.3 has specified this case:

I have to name my interface method like this: **findByTabelaArquivoVersao**

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Find your Arquivo by Versao from `ArquivoRepository`, and then call `arquivo.getTabelas()` and `getCampos()` for each of them to get the collection of campos you want.

**Option 2**

Define your own `@Query` in `CampoRepository`, like so:

```
@Query("select c from Campo c where c.tabela.arquivo.versao = :versao")
Page<Campo> findAllByArquivoVersao(@Param("versao") String versao, Pageable pageable);
```

If you wanted `Campos` by partial comparison of their `versao` you can do something like this:

```
@Query("select c from Campo c where upper(c.tabela.arquivo.versao) like concat('%',upper(:versao),'%')")
Page<Campo> findAllByArquivoVersao(@Param("versao") String versao, Pageable pageable);
```

Without knowing exactly how you have designed your entities (fetching, nullability, ...) this is as much as I can guess.

I did not test any of this code.